# How fast is sqrt() in c++

Tags: c++, math.sqrt

I would like to ask about sqrt() function in library 
in c++, I have an integer number and I want to know if there is an integer-square root fo this number...like 16 --> 4, and if not return -1
here is the function:

```
long long SQRT(Long long x)
{
    long long i;
    for (i = 0; i <= x / 2; i++)
      if (i * i == x)
        return i;
    return -1;
}
```

but it takes much more time than `sqrt()`...can any one  explain me that...thanks in advance

Comment: Your method is too straight forward and is obviously will be too slow.

Comment: Check this link out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi. It shows several ways of implementing sqrt and running times.

Comment: To speed up your code, you can try [Fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) approach

Comment: I'm flagging this question as too broad. Fast and accurate implementations of functions like these require thorough knowledge of numerical math and/or calculus. The same would go for questions about many other `<math.h>` functions.

Comment: thanks i got the answer from your links...thanks very much